# Rank vector with some equal values

Tags: r

I got a question. I have a really large vector and some of its values are equal. What I want to get is the rank of its values, the biggest value would be rank #1, the smallest the last rank (in the example below rank #6). I tried `rank(-x, ties.method = "min")` but the solution is not correct in my case.

```
x <- c(1,10,2,5,5,8,3)
Rank <- rank(-x,ties.method = "min")
Rank
[1] 7 1 6 3 3 2 5
```

But Rank should be:

```
Rank
[1] 6 1 5 3 3 2 4
```

Can you help me? Why is the 4th rank missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert to factor and back to numeric

```
as.numeric(as.factor(rank(-x)))
#[1] 6 1 5 3 3 2 4
```

Answer (score 5):

We can do this with `dense_rank`

```
library(dplyr)
dense_rank(-x)
#[1] 6 1 5 3 3 2 4
```

Answer (score 5):

What you can do, if you don't want any values skipped is this:

```
as.integer(factor(-x))
[1] 6 1 5 3 3 2 4
```

Hope that answers your question.